# Excel - Specificity to FPR

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column of values in range `0 - 1` (specificity) and I need to create a new column with the equivalent FPR values which is `1 - specificity`. Which function can I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With specificity values in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=1-A1
```

and copy down

Comment: I was missing the "copy down" thing. Thanks !!!